# Is there any de-facto standarized way for passing conditions to REST APIs? (with Ruby/JS wrappers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, rest

I am implementing an app that uses RoR for the backend and AngularJS for the frontend.

These layers are totally split, frontend talks to the backend over REST API. Due to nature of the system sometimes it must pass certain SQL-like conditions to the request in order to limit amount of retreived data.

Are there any de-facto standarized ways of doing this? Some conventions for naming parameters etc.? Preferably some solutions that have their Ruby implementations in gems, and JS libraries ready for AngularJS.

I don't want to reimplement the wheel.